# Force auto-submit a Google Form using app-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am using a code which closes the FORM at specified time. So what happened is some students are failing to submit it before the time limit and their responses are not being recorded.

Is there any way to force auto-submit a google form at specified end-time for all the users who are writing the quiz lets say!

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this documentation about [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) which  let Apps Script run a function automatically when a certain event occurs. It is similar to [simple triggers for Google Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#getting_started) like `onOpen()`, but they can respond to additional events, and they behave differently.

There are several installable triggers for Google Apps and you can use an installable [form-submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers) trigger that runs when a user responds to a form.

Be noted that there are two versions of the form-submit trigger, [one for Google Forms itself](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events) and [one for Sheets if the form submits to a spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events).